# How to assign a keys of an array as a function's parameters?

Tags: javascript, arrays, arrow-functions, destructuring, es6-modules

I have a JavaScript module that exported with arrow function with 3 parameters, the following example:

// getMonth.js module

```js
export default (date, type, ...rest)  => {
  // Represent this return exmaple
  return date + ' ' + type + ' ' + rest
}
```

In the main file, I have an array that I want to Assign the keys of the array as function's parameters

```js
import getMonth from '../modules/month.js'
  
let splitedParams = ['2016/07/14', 'full']

getMonth({date, type, ...rest} = splitedParams)
```

But this implementation isn't right and I got some error, How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: `getMonth.apply(undefined, splitedParams)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [function.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

```
import getMonth from '../modules/month.js'

let splitedParams = ['2016/07/14', 'full']

getMonth.apply(null, splitedParams)
```

Or use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator): `...`

```
getMonth(...splitedParams)
```

See it demonstrated in this example below:

```js
let splitedParams = ['2016/07/14', 'full']

//using Function.prototype.apply()
getMonth.apply(null, splitedParams);

//using the spread operator
getMonth(...splitedParams);

function getMonth(date, type) {
  console.log('getMonth() - date: ', date, 'type: ', type);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) `...` to assign the values from the array to the function parameters:

```
import getMonth from '../modules/month.js'

const splitedParams = ['2016/07/14', 'full']

getMonth(...splitedParams)
```